# Deadlock on 1.7.0.2 CE Checkout

Tags: magento-1.7, database, mysql

I'm facing a 'thousand years of pain' Magento deadlock issue on the last step of the checkout. Here's the exception:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction' in /var/www/app/code/community/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:258
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/app/code/community/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(258): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ma...', Array)
#5 /var/www/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ma...', Array)
#6 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Abstract.php(177): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ma...')
#7 /var/www/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Abstract.php(51): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Abstract->updateGridRecords('300151')
#8 [internal function]: Mage_Sales_Model_Abstract->afterCommitCallback()
#9 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(110): call_user_func(Array)
#10 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(79): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract->commit()
#11 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(169): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_commitTransaction()
#12 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#13 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#14 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(774): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#15 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(512): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#16 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#17 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#18 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /var/www/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /var/www/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

I have tried:

- reindex from shell
- disable all local modules
- https://gist.github.com/netalico/7917297
- Philwinkle_DeadlockRetry
- Increase lock timeout

with no success.

Comment: What table is being inserted into?  Begins with ma....

Comment: @philwinkle also I was going to ask, what  innodb_lock_wait_timeout works best... I've got it as 120 but I'm thinking to reduce it back down to 50.

Comment: Indexing can cause table locks, so make sure they run when people aren't on. Additionally, mysqldump can also lock tables so you may also want to put the site in maintenance during a full reindex on a large database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bear in mind that a query that hits a lock timeout is not the same as a deadlocked query, the two are different and as such, the diagnosis tools are different.

#### To review deadlocks

Just open a MySQL CLI prompt and enter,

```
show innodb status
```

It will print the SQL query for the last deadlock encountered.

If you are using Percona MySQL, you can also use their toolkit to log deadlocks.

#### To review lock wait timeouts

Use,

```
show process list
```

During the time that you are placing the order in the checkout, and you will be able to observe the current query holding the lock and trace the cause from there.

You could also enable the slow query log, set the timeout lower than the lock wait timeout, and you'll have a log of queries blocking the others.

Comment: I had to run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` however this does not show me any deadlocks. So yes, maybe I did get a lock timeout and a deadlock query confused.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QFHrWSmn